# Calling a WebAPI from an Azure Bot

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, bots, botframework

I am new to Azure Bot programming (C#) and cannot find good articles on this topic.

I would like to let a user 'subscribe' to a mailing list using the Bot.  I build a Form dialog and Form Flow.  It asks a user for their email address.

What I need to do is post that to an external WebAPI (json) and get a response and handle the response.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to call a WebAPI from a Bot?

```
    public async Task Subscribe(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        context.Call(SubscribeForm.BuildFormDialog(FormOptions.PromptInStart), SubscribeFormComplete);
    }

    private async Task SubscribeFormComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SubscribeForm> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var form = await result;
            if (form != null)
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Thanks for subscribing! You can always remove yourself by typing unsubscribe.");
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Form returned empty response!");
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("I am sorry you decided not to subscribe! If you change your mind just type 'subscribe' again.");
        }

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }


        [Serializable]
public class SubscribeForm
{
    [Prompt("What is your email address?")]
    [Required()]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public static IForm<SubscribeForm> BuildForm()
    {
        // Builds an IForm<T> based on BasicForm
        return new FormBuilder<SubscribeForm>()
            .Message("We often send out updates on new features. We don't spam.  You can type 'quit' to cancel this.")
           .Build();
    }

    public static IFormDialog<SubscribeForm> BuildFormDialog(FormOptions options = FormOptions.PromptInStart)
    {
        // Generated a new FormDialog<T> based on IForm<BasicForm>
        return FormDialog.FromForm(BuildForm, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it be different when done from a bot? You can just make the request as you would normally.

Comment: Bots and form flows have 'stacks' and parent/child nuances to them.  Just looking for suggestions on where to place code for the WebAPI call.  For example in the formcompleted method or some other place, and how to handle async and callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how I call Microsoft's Cognitive service LUIS, I have the method on an static class, and the method is async.

Method:

```
 public static class CognitiveHelper
    {
        private const string UrlLuis = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/a267a797-9584-41a5-83f3-xxxxxxxxx?subscription-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=";
    public static async Task<LuisObjects> GetLuisAnswer(string textToEvaluate)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textToEvaluate)) throw new ArgumentException("Null argument");

                textToEvaluate= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textToEvaluate);
                var urlLuisWithRequest = UrlLuis + textToEvaluate;

                var client = new HttpClient();
                var body = new { };

                var serializedBody = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(body);
                byte[] bodyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedBody );

                using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(bodyByte))
                {
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    var response= await client.GetAsync(urlLuisWithRequest );
                    var responseContent= await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var resultTextAnalysis= javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<LuisResult>(responseContent);
                    return new LuisObjects()
                    {
                        Entities= resultTextAnalysis.entities.ToList(),
                        TopScoringIntent = resultTextAnalysis.topScoringIntent
                    };
                }
            }
}
```

Call:

```
  var luisResponse = await CognitiveHelper.GetLuisAnswer(activity.Text);
```